# Positioning a button by percentage in CSS

Tags: html, css, position, percentage

So I'm trying to position a button with percentages so its position doesn't get ruined when the screen gets re-sized, but I'm not sure how. For now I'm using px but obviously it doesn't work. Would I need to somehow obtain the screen size, store it in a variable, and then use that to calculate a position, or is there an easier way?

index.html

```
<body>
    <webview src="https://bapbap.gg"></webview>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black">
    <style>
        .ExitButton {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: 'Archivo Black';
        color: #6B7075;
        border-color: transparent; 
        background-color: transparent;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-bottom: 638px;
        margin-left: 470px;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;

    } .ExitButton:hover {
        background-color: rgb(150, 5, 5);
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

        </style>
      <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('Are you sure you want to exit BapClient?')">EXIT</button>
</button>
</body>
```

style.css

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

webview {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: The `absolute` element must have a `position: relative` parent to stick to the positioning. In your case, replace `marging-left` & `marging-bottom` by `left: Xpx` and `bottom: Xpx` and set `body` to `position; relative` and work your way up by fine-tunning the percentages of `top` and `bottom`

Comment: I did so, but the issue is still there unfortunately. I attached my style.css file just in case there might be something there messing it up.

Comment: where do you want to position your button? in full screen or in center or what?

Comment: So essentially on the menu there's 4 buttons in the top left corner and I want to make it the fifth.

Answer (score 1):

I saw your comment and I think you want to make a navigation bar and at the end of it an Exit button

remove position: absolute, margin-top and margin-bottom from the ExitButton class

```
<div class="nav">
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button1')">button1</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button2')">button2</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button3')">button3</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('Are you sure you want to exit BapClient?')">EXIT</button>
</div>
```

now using diplay: flex on .nav you can play with the position of your buttons and make them relative to your screen size, for more info [check this](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp).

```html
<body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black">
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    webview {
      flex: 1;
    }
    
    .ExitButton {
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-family: 'Archivo Black';
      color: #6B7075;
      border-color: transparent;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .ExitButton:hover {
      background-color: rgb(150, 5, 5);
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .nav {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: start;
      gap: 5%;
    }
    
    .nav2 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: end;
      gap: 5%;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="nav">
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button1')">button1</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button2')">button2</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button3')">button3</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button4')">button3</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('Are you sure you want to exit BapClient?')">EXIT</button>
  </div>
  <div class="nav2">
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button1')">button1</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button2')">button2</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button3')">button3</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('button4')">button3</button>
    <button class="ExitButton" onclick="alert('Are you sure you want to exit BapClient?')">EXIT</button>
  </div>
  etc..
  </button>
</body>
```

I know there are many other ways to do this, but I like this way of managing navigation bars.

Comment: Hey, so actually I only needed one button and after changing up some things from your code I got the button to scale correctly, but now there's white space under it when I re-position it.

Comment: can you please send the code i can take a look at it, or just upload it to GitHub and send me the repository name